# How to write the correct value in the nested object if I use a formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Given an array with fields whose names match the names from the form object, I'm trying to write a nested value, but for some reason the formik does not understand how to write a nested value, this only works for values ​​from the top level

I will leave a link to codesandbox in the comment

```
export default function App() {
  const form = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      login: "",
      about: {
        age: "",
        rank: "",
        car: {
          name: "",
          years: ""
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const fields = [
    {
      name: { title: "Your name", fields: {} },
      login: { title: "Your login", fields: {} },
      about: {
        title: "About",
        fields: {
          age: { title: "Your age", fields: {} },
          rank: { title: "Your rank", fields: {} },
          car: {
            title: "Your car",
            fields: {
              name: { title: "Car name", fields: {} },
              years: { title: "Car years", fields: {} }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ];
  const { values, handleChange } = form;

  console.log("VALUES", values);

  const itemsRender = (item, idx) => {
    const key = Object.keys(item).at(-1);
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <p>{item[key]?.title}</p>
        <input
          name={key}
          value={values[key]}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder={item[key].title}
        />

        {!isEmpty(item[key]?.fields) && (
          <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
            {Object.entries(item[key]?.fields).map(itemsRender)}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <>{fields.map(itemsRender)}</>;
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-goldwasser-xc8wv2?file=/src/App.js:0-1485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `name` and `value` properties to include the full path to the nested field

```js
<input
  name={`${key}.${nestedFieldName}`} // Include the nested field's path
  value={getIn(values, `${key}.${nestedFieldName}`)} // Get nested value using getIn from formik
  onChange={handleChange}
  placeholder={fieldObj.title}
/>
```

Your code is only handling one level of nesting.
 For deeper levels of nesting, you need to recursively render and handle the nested fields

```js
{Object.entries(item[key]?.fields).map(([nestedFieldName, fieldObj]) => (
  <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} key={nestedFieldName}>
    <p>{fieldObj.title}</p>
    <input
      name={`${key}.${nestedFieldName}`}
      value={getIn(values, `${key}.${nestedFieldName}`)}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={fieldObj.title}
    />
    {fieldObj.fields && (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
        {Object.entries(fieldObj.fields).map(itemsRender)}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
))}
```

Finally, instead of using `handleChange` directly for nested fields, you should use Formik's `setFieldValue` to update the values of nested fields.
You can access `setFieldValue` from the form object you have:

```js
onChange={(e) => {
  form.setFieldValue(`${key}.${nestedFieldName}`, e.target.value);
}}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-lumiere-zy6t3w)

Comment: Bro, thanks!!!
Its good!

And tell me please, how to remove these extra intupy?
https://imgur.com/a/zGjCihF